# How to debug a blackberry verification error?

Tags: java, debugging, blackberry, java-me

All I get is:

> "Module 'my-app' has verification
>   error 'xxxx' at offset '1646'

Which according to [blackberry](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800708/800647/Support_-_MIDlet_has_verification_error_at_offset.html?nodeid=800711&vernum=0), contains information that is of no use to third party developpers.

I looked in the buglog (with the 'catfail' option), and all I found was a method on which it crashed, not why. funny thing is, when I remove this method from my application, it still logs the same method for causing the error. It's kind of strange.

extra info: My app contains LWUIT, and the blackberryport

I've also read the [KB article DB-00744](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/832062/Support_-_Preventing_verification_errors.html?nodeid=1499031&vernum=0), which suggest a verification error can mean any of the following '14' errors.  Is it random, or is there a method behind this logic?

Comment: My collegue found the error: an external library supported touch, and we were building for blackberry 4.6, which does not support touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I looked in the buglog (with the 'catfail' option), and all I found was a method on which it crashed, not why. funny thing is, when I remove this method from my application, it still logs the same method for causing the error. It's kind of strange.

You must have made a mistake somewhere in your build / deploy / test process .... assuming that you are talking about one of your application's own methods, not just some method that your application calls.  Try doing it all again.

> Is it random? or is their a method behind this logic?

One would assume that these are all issues that have been found to contribute to in verification errors with various customer apps on various releases of the Blackberry platform.  It be said though that a couple of them seem a bit odd.  For instance unnecessary imports (3) should be harmless, and using "package private" incorrectly (4) should cause Java compilation errors ... I'd have thought.  And I don't like the fact that the list often don't say *why* these measures might be necessary.

Judging from this note, I get the feeling that some of the tools in the Blackberry development toolchain are rather poorly engineered.  (Surely it cannot be *that* hard for the verifier to produce informative diagnostics instead of undocumented "internal" error codes.  And some of the things mentioned "smell" like workarounds for bugs.)

Comment: It does look like a lot of the weird ones are indirectly related to the possibility of conflicting names - perhaps even for internal member variables.  Though it seems odd since presumably those names are not maintained in the bytecode...

Comment: An unnecessary import will have no impact whatsoever on generated code.  And a "missing" visibility will either be harmless, or cause a compilation error.  If either of these are not true, then the Java compiler is buggy.

Comment: I was referring more to the package private usage.   That said, it would be nice to have better tools -- if this is catchable at run-time, it's also catchable compile time and shouldn't be a guessing game.  (I'm currently having this same issue on 4 of 12 BB SDK simulators -- many of them running the same OS version.)